Setting up reverse DNS for home email server with IPv6 on Linux Ubuntu 22.04 or Debian
I'm trying to set up an email server at home using Ubuntu 22.04 and IPv6. I would like to configure a reverse DNS for my IPv6 address to ensure reliable email delivery.
I've followed this guide to set up a static IP.
Now, I'd like to set up a reverse DNS for this IPv6 address. I'm considering using either BIND or DNSMasq as my DNS server. Could someone guide me on how to configure reverse DNS for an public IPv6 address on a home connection using one of these DNS servers?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Your ISP "owns" the IP blocks your public addresses (both IPv6 and IPv4) are in, so they also control the reverse DNS zones for those addresses. So basically, you have to get the ISP to make the relevant reverse entries in their DNS server. You can't do it yourself.

Yesterday, in contact with support, they were completely lost and threw the responsibility on me, saying I had to do this with a DNS server at home.

Were they talking about delegating it to you from their DNS server (which would be reasonable), or just thinking you could set it up completely by yourself (you can't; they control the parent zone, so they either need to create the records themselves or delegate it to you)?
